# How to fix type warning for radius settings in React app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, recharts

I have a React app that uses recharts to draw a bar graph. I use a function to check the data and decide whether to round the corners of a cell. It looks like the following:

```
function customizedCell(this: { column: number; color: string }, entry, index, array) {     
  // Logic to determine which corners to round.
  return <Cell key={index} fill={this.color} radius={[0, 30, 30, 0]} />;  
}
```

And it is called from inside a react component like so:

```
<Bar dataKey="mykey" stackId="1">
  {this.data.map(customizedCell, { column: 3, color: '#AABBCC' })}
</Bar>
```

Everything works fine, but there is a warning like below for each of the number in the radius value array when I run the app with npm:

```
TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

How do I avoid this warning? `radius={'[0, 30, 30, 0]'}`, `radius={'0 30 30 0'}`, etc. will break the code (no rounding effect).

Comment: Where does `Cell` come from? It's possible the types are wrong, but it's not clear whether they're types you've written.

Comment: Cell is a recharts component to render a block in a stacked bar.  You are right.  The 'radius' for <Cell> is not the same as the 'radius' for <Bar> and only takes one value instead of four.  So somehow using the wrong settings get me the wanted result, but using the correct settings will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your type problem, you could first turn each value from number to string by putting them in quotes: 30 => '30'.

However, afterwards there will be a type error on the `radius` prop. To fix this one, you can translate its type to `unknown`, and a second time to `string` to remove the type warning.

Both changes should look like the following:

```js
return <Cell key={index} fill={this.color} radius={['0', '30', '30', '0'] as unknown as string} />;
```

Comment: I'll change the code to set the radius in <Bar> instead of <Cell>, but your solution works great.  Thanks.